# access javascript variable into the .ashx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ashx

I have a JavaScript, which returns 2 variables. I just want to access those variables in the generic handler(ashx) page but I can't. Can anybody give some suggestion?

```
var myArray = [txt, value];
var url = "insertComments.ashx?dat=" + myArray.join();
```

Comment: What is the problem? Sending the value or reading it on the server?

Comment: it is not going inside the ashx page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Javascript :

```
var url = "insertComments.ashx?datTxt=" + txt + "&" + "datValue=" + value;
```

and in handler access that values with :

```
string txt = context.Request.Params["datTxt"];
string val = context.Request.Params["datValue"];
```